# Program isn't running on VS Code, FullyQualifiedError and gcc.exe error

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, compiler-errors, runtime-error

[Image of terminal showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4sxo.jpg)
On running C program it is showing
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: NativeCommandFailed and gcc.exe error in the VS code terminal.

I tried using V
Terminal commands to ensure the source code file is compiling correct, used gcc and output commands to run the program in terminal.
I also reinstalled VS code thrice, but it also didn't worked.

Comment: Wow, a blurry, angled, rotated, actual shot of a screen.... Better provide your textual info additionally as text here. Reading [ask] and taking the [tour] would probably also help you to improve your question. Also please give your reasons for assuming that the third and fourth line from the bottom (I cannot quote them, because, you know, picture...) are not the relevant detail of what makes your attempt fail.

Comment: The error says it couldn't find your source code.  You said you tried some things in the 2nd paragraph but it's not clear to me what the outcome was.

Comment: The outcome was the error

Comment: Please don't post images of code and errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if there are typos in the file name (obvious, but worth stating)
2. Make sure the files really do exist in your current directory and you are not just viewing an unsaved or unwritten file. Type `ls` into the terminal and see if the source file is listed there (use `dir` if you are using default windows shell). If you are not in the correct working directory, `cd` to the correct directory or use #2 below.
3. Try typing out the absolute path of the input file (ex. `C:\path\to\file.c`). You can use `pwd` on windows powershell to print the absolute path of the working directory.

Worth mentioning, please make the image of the error as easy to view as possible (i.e., correct orientation, clear image, etc.).